# Show that if A is a Subset of B, then A is dominated by B

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Definition of A is dominated by B: There is an injective function from a to B.

Remark: For finite sets A,B
A is dominated by b is equivalent to the cardinality of A is less than or equal to B

Proof: 
Let A,B be sets.
Assume A is a subset of  B, i.e., the cardinality of A is less than or equal to B. However, for finite sets, that is the definition of A being dominated b meant.

I was wondering if my proof is incomplete or worse incorrect. Anyone care to help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is $A$ subset of $B$?

Comment: We just assume that A is a subset of B.

Comment: why.................

Comment: Note: for a mathematician, `b` and `B` are taken to represent different things. So don’t use them interchangeably.

Comment: Well, if you assume that $A$ is a subset of $B$, then you have shown that any set dominates any subset. Most sets aren't subsets of one another, so this proof is mostly non-valid. Unless you back up that assumption with valid reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

if A is a subset of B ,the identity function I:A--> B ,I(x)=x ,is an injection .